# Trigger de DDL Oracle , identificar um "drop column"

Tags: oracle, pl-sql, oracle11g

No Oracle é possível criar Triggers de DDL (Data Definition Language) algo do tipo

```
create or replace trigger trg_ddl
   before ddl
    on database
  declare
  begin
  ...
  end;
```

Minha , dúvida , como reconhecer um evento de exclusão de coluna de uma tabela ?

```
ALTER TABLE <TABLE> DROP COLUMN <COLUMN>
```

Dúvida sobre síntaxe, espero estar de acordo às normas.

Comment: é comum fazerem drop das colunas ai? só curiosidade, geralmente não se faz muitas triggers para esses eventos, permissões de drop devem ser mais restritas... sobre sua pergunta, veja essas variávies do `oracle` e teste na sua trigger: `ORA_SYSEVENT` e `ORA_DICT_OBJ_NAME` a primeira costuma trazer no evento "alter", "truncate", pode ser que pegue o "drop" também, a segunda vai mostrar a tabela (estou pensando que sua trigger deve ser para o database todo, ou schema), isso já deve ajudar a pegar alguma coisa

Comment: Tem um processo automático do ERP fazendo lambança ele não acha a coluna do Oracle no dicionário e dropa as colunas.

Comment: Como quase sempre alguém já passou pelo problema. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43980081/oracle-ddl-trigger