# Revogar privilégios específicos do comando ALTER TABLE do MySQL 5.6.44

Tags: mysql, sql

Preciso impedir que uma coluna seja removida acidentalmente ao rodar uma migration em um banco de dados MySQL v5.6.44, para isso pensei em limitar privilégios, porém mesmo removendo a permissão de "DROP" para um usuário, ainda sim é possível executar o comando "ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN".

Eu estava seguindo a doc de referência: (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_alter).

Com isso minha dúvida é: É possível limitar os privilégios do comando ALTER TABLE?

Comment: Passei por um problems parecido em Oracle , pensei numa trigger de ddl , pelo que vi também é possível em MySql , a trigger impede um "drop column" https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=2418 , acabei não precisando usar a trigger https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/455233/trigger-de-ddl-oracle-identificar-um-drop-column

Comment: Tentei seguir a sintaxe da documentação, mas na versão que estou usando ele não está aceitando os evento DDL, acusa erro de sintaxe.

Comment: Não uso Mysql fui na semelhança , mas você tem histórico de drop neste casos !?

Comment: Temos mais o risco, por conta do ORM que adotamos criar migrations gerando drop de colunas ao invés de change, minha equipe está ignorando essa funcionalidade pra prod e usando somente em dev, até acharmos uma solução melhor.

Answer (score 0):

Experimenta fazer o seguinte comando de REVOKE para desabilitar o privilégio:

```
REVOKE ALTER FROM *object* FROM *user*;
```

Comment: Nesse caso, eu consigo revogar o ALTER com sucesso, mas no meu cenário eu precisaria revogar apenas o ALTER que fosse usado em conjunto com DROP